# Rundeck implicit variable

Tags: rundeck

Run dick gives us the ability to define options to be entered by the its GUI, is there any capability to have job variable based on the input without the end user of the job seeing it?

E.g, if the the user choose the product and the environment and the product behind LB, I want to use a script internally to define new job variable and assign it the port number that could be used later on within the job steps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.

You can add a new option whith `Allowed Values` set to `Remote URL`, then put the URL to your script which will return the actual value based on other options.

For exmaple
`http://localhost/cgi-bin/getPort.py?environment=${option.environment.value}&product=${option.product.value}`

[Rundeck Manual option-model-provider](https://rundeck.org/2.6.2/manual/jobs.html?utm_source=rundeckapp&utm_medium=2.6.2%20Linux%20java%201.7.0_191&utm_campaign=helplink&utm_content=editOpts/edit#option-model-provider)